# Disable mobile requests for ipad using Mobylette

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Id like my mobile web experience to exclude iPad devices. I have tried installing a before filter like this:

```
def mobylette_device_override
  if (request_device?(:ipad))
    session[:mobylette_override] = :ignore_mobile
  else
    session[:mobylette_override] = nil
  end
end
```

This has the odd behavior of incorrectly rendering the normal website. I suspect something is still tying into the mobile code path. Is there a better way to selectively disable Mobylette.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the way you currently have it setup is that for ipad you will ignore the mobile and render mobile for everything else (including regular browser). Probably better solution would be to override the fallback on the mobilet config (mobylette_config)

```
mobylette_config do |config|
  config[:fallback_chains] = {
    mobile: [:mobile, :html],
    ipad: [:html],
    ...
  }
end
```

Comment: That worked, but I had to track down somewhere I had code like this:
      elsif is_mobile_request?
which needed to become
      elsif is_mobile_request? && !request_device?(:ipad)